# Should I use "was" or "were" when presenting "a X and a Y"?

Tags: subject-verb-agreement

Example:

> The only house-like **feature/features was/were** a window and a
>   double-layer roof.

What's the correct option and why?

Answer (score 5):

In a statement using an *intransitive* verb (to be), the predicate refers to the subject. "a window and a double-layer roof" and "house-like features" are the same in this context.
So the subject will be plural too, and the verb will match the subject.

> The only house-like **features were** a window and a double-layer roof.